# Is there a way to search for PDFs by the number of pages they have?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, google-search

e.g. I often use `filetype:pdf` to search for PDFs on Google.  It would be great if I could combine this with a filesize or number of pages keyword, or even if I could just preview these data in the search results. . .Any suggestions of extensions or other methods which might enable this?

Comment: I doubt you will get an answer to your question. The number of pages requires the document to be rendered. It is not some kind of metadata stored in the document.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14644354/2224701